# Date formating in SQL query vs c# for performance reason

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, telerik-reporting

I'm using Telerik tool to generate report, on production server it takes too long to load report. My goal is to optimize reports without changing DB schema, so to add indexes is out of context.
My queries do a lot of date formatting and case-when statements, so what is the best practice of doing so considering SQL vs c# code vs Telerik reporting tool. And will it improve performance if I take it off the query and do formatting in the c# code.

Comment: You improve performance by profiling your report and targeting bottlenecks. You do not do it by guessing what code would be easy/fun to change. It is very unlikely you will be able to improve your report much until after you are able to change the schema.

Comment: No one can assist without sample code. And if database optimization is not an option you're probably not going to make much progress. Anyway... the first step to optimizing this from the code side is understanding which bits of code take the longest. There is not magic fairy dust to speed things up you need to provide sample code and make some effort at analysis

Comment: The best practice is to format dates for display purposes in the presentation layer rather than the data layer.  I can't say if it will improve performance in your situation.